# Press button in listView adapter to get data in this row

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

I have a listView that shows data that in sqlite, I'm using baseAdapter. 
The list row contains text and button.

I press the button in each row to give me each data of the selected row from the database (not pressing the row itself)

This is code of listView:

```
tipsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

 list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tipList);

 do {
  map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(DAO.TIP_ID, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(0))));
            map.put(DAO.TIP_CONTENT, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(1))));
            map.put(DAO.TIP_FAVORITE, c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(c.getColumnName(2))));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            tipsList.add(map);

        } while (c.moveToNext());


        tipsAdapter = new TipsAdapter(getActivity(), tipsList, tipType, db);
        list.setAdapter(tipsAdapter);
```

And this is code of TipsAdapter.java

```
public class TipsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Context context;
    Typeface tf;
    String tipID;
    String tipText;
    String isFavorite;
    DAO db;
    HashMap<String, String> quote;
    int selectedTipType;

    public TipsAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d, int selectedTipType, DAO db) {
        activity = a;
        data = d;
        context = a;
        this.selectedTipType = selectedTipType;
        this.db = db;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    // ==============================================================================

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi = convertView;
        if (convertView == null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tip_list_row, null);

        TextView tipContent = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.tip_text); // tip
        final ImageView favStar = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.favorite_star);

        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(activity.getAssets(), "fonts/bauhausm_0.ttf");
        tipContent.setTypeface(tf);

        quote = new HashMap<String, String>();
        quote = data.get(position);

        tipText = quote.get(DAO.TIP_CONTENT).trim();


        favStar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(View view) {

                        // I want here get all data like tipId - tipText - tipFavotite of the current row in toast
              }

            });



        return vi;
    }
     }
```

How to get the data of the current row when press the button?
Hope anyone got my mean. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Solved it by myself by making `position` as `final` and put `quote = data.get(position);` inside the listener of the button.

Comment: did you set the tag of your button view? if you did set it. it should not return null. Ok good. if you did you solved it by your self.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can set the tag of your button.

```
favStar.setTag(position);
favStar.setOnClickListener (new OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

           int position = (int) view.getTag();

           HashMap<String, String>() quote = data.get(position);

           String tipText = qout.get(DAO.TIP_CONTENT);
           String tipContent = ......;

   }
}
```

Comment: it gives me NullPointerException in this line `int position = (Integer) view.getTag();`